# Kafka Received exception when fetching the next record from uvtopic1-0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am getting this error ***Received exception when fetching the next record from uvtopic1-0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.***

```
public class KafkaConsumerPoc2 {

    private static final Integer count = 10000;

    public static final String KAFKA_SERVER_URL = "0.0.0.0";
    public static final int KAFKA_SERVER_PORT = 29092;

    static ExecutorService executorService;

    static Map<String, KafkaProducer<String, String>> topicWiseProducerMap = new HashMap<String, KafkaProducer<String, String>>();

    private static Map<String, KafkaConsumer<String, String>> topicConsumerMap = new HashMap<String, KafkaConsumer<String, String>>();

    private static Properties getConsumerProp(String topicName) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KAFKA_SERVER_URL + ":" + KAFKA_SERVER_PORT);
        String grupId = topicName + "-grup";
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, grupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "1000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());

        return props;
    }

    public static KafkaConsumer<String, String> getConsumerByTopicName(String topicName) {
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = topicConsumerMap.get(topicName);
        if (consumer == null) {
            consumer = registerConsumer(topicName);
        }
        return consumer;
    }

    public static KafkaConsumer<String, String> registerConsumer(String topicName) {
        Properties pro = getConsumerProp(topicName);
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(pro);
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(topicName));
        topicConsumerMap.put(topicName, consumer);
        return consumer;
    }

    private static void startThreadForTopicListening(String topic) {
        executorService.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {

                KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = getConsumerByTopicName(topic);

                topicListener(topic, consumer);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public static void topicListener(String topic, KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer) {
        try {

            System.out.println("************* Read message starts *****************************");

            ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));

            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : consumerRecords) {

                if (record.value() != null) {
                    System.out.println("Received message: (" + record.value() + ") at offset " + record.offset()
                            + " topic : " + record.topic());
                }
            }

            System.out.println("************* Read message ends *****************************");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            topicListener(topic, consumer);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Main starts");

        Integer sizeOfExecutors = 2;

        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(sizeOfExecutors);

        startThreadForWriting(KafkaClientPoc2.topic1);
        startThreadForTopicListening(KafkaClientPoc2.topic1);

    }

    private static void startThreadForWriting(String topic) {
        executorService.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                    KafkaClientPoc2.writeSingleMsgInTopic(KafkaClientPoc2.topic1, "Msg:" + i);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public static void writeSingleMsgInTopic(String topicName, String msg) {
        System.out.println("#################### Write Msg starts ############################");
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = getProducer(topicName);
        try {
            ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, msg);
            producer.send(record);
            producer.flush();
            System.out.println("writer > Sent message: (" + msg + ")");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("#################### Write Msg ends ############################");
    }

    public static KafkaProducer<String, String> getProducer(String topicName) {
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = topicWiseProducerMap.get(topicName);
        if (producer == null) {
            producer = registerProducer(topicName);
        }
        return producer;
    }

    public static Properties getProducerProp() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "0.0.0.0:29092");
        prop.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        prop.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        prop.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 1);

        return prop;
    }

    private static KafkaProducer<String, String> registerProducer(String topicName) {
        System.out.println("Creating new Producer");
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(getProducerProp());
        topicWiseProducerMap.put(topicName, producer);
        return producer;
    }

}
```

Following is my stack trace

> org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Received exception when
> fetching the next record from uvtopic1-0. If needed, please seek past
> the record to continue consumption.   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1598)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1700(Fetcher.java:1453)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:686)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:637)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1276)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1237)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210)
> at
> com.vp.loaddata.vploaddata.poc2.KafkaConsumerPoc2.topicListener(KafkaConsumerPoc2.java:80)
> at
> com.vp.loaddata.vploaddata.poc2.KafkaConsumerPoc2.topicListener(KafkaConsumerPoc2.java:101)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by downgrading the kafka-clients version from 3. something to 2.81